# How to extract characters from a string without using substr()

Tags: r, string

I would like to know if there is any other better way of numbering and extracting characters from a string in R.

Suppose my string is:

```
s <- "foo"
```

In R there is no sequencing of the characters like in Java, wherein you can get the ith element. `s[0]` should return "f"

I tried using `substr(s,1,1)` but I think it is not the most efficient way to iterate, just trying to find a better way?

Comment: Do you mean like  `strsplit("cat", split = "")[[1]] `?

Comment: Can I ask why you *think it is not the most efficient way to iterate*? Can you show what kind of iteration you're trying to do.

Comment: It also depends on what you want to get out of the transaction. The `substr` function returns a string with the characters that you specify—`substr('abcde',1,5)` returns `'abcde'`. The `strsplit` function returns a list with one vector of single characters—`strsplit('abcde', split='')` returns [[1]][1] 'a','b','c','d','e'`. If you do want the vector, it is slightly more efficient to wrap `substr` inside a `strsplit` call than to slice the output of `strsplit`.

Comment: +1 to PoGibas: it's hard to think of a more efficient way to do this (since this is one of the things that `substr()` was designed to do. If you needed **really** high efficiency (you needed to do this operation millions of times, and it was the bottleneck in your code) you might be able to write a dedicated first-character-extractor in Rcpp, but it probably wouldn't be much faster.

Comment: In java or C I can refer to an element of  a String S <- "test"   as S[i], but in R, I do not see a way of doing it, I will have to use strsplit() or substr() and then extract character by character, isn't there any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

If you do

```
strsplit("cat", split = "")[[1]]
```

You will get

```
 [1] "c" "a" "t"
```

Which you could thing use for vectorized functions or in a loop.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please tell me what's the significance of using [[1]]

Comment: strsplit() returns a list and you want the content of the first element of the list, which is [[1]].   So if you gave strsplitI() a vector of strings it would return a list of results, one element per string.